# Gedmo doesn't fill dates on record flush

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using Gedmo for it's Timestampable options, to automatically add `created_at` and `updated_at` dates but getting error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created_at' cannot be null

Why they are not filled? That's how I am implementing it:

```
#[ORM\Column]
#[Gedmo\Timestampable(on: 'create')]
private ?\DateTime $createdAt;

#[ORM\Column]
#[Gedmo\Timestampable]
private ?\DateTime $updatedAt;
```

Doing the things as per the documentation. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Did you [configure the bundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/current/configuration.html#activate-the-extensions-you-want)?

Comment: @msg Yes, didn't work.

Comment: Hi, did you also add the configuration inside doctrine.yaml ? Please update the comment with the configuration if you can.

Comment: @TomaTomov did you solve this?